# How to write a Function in OCAML, that returns a list, in which the second list is inserted into the first one

Tags: ocaml

How to write a function, that takes in two lists and an integer
(for instance: int  n) as an input and then returns a list in which the second list is inserted into the first list, to the n-th place (that's why the function also takes an INT as an input).

Here is what I've done already, but I seem to have an issue with the "mutable variable "list1", of the type "prev", I'm not exactly sure if it's even called "prev" at all. The function code should work though, but the compiler gives me this error:

line 12, characters 18-22:
Error: This record pattern is expected to have type list
The field prev does not belong to type list

The error, that the compiler gives me for the "prev" mutable variable is basically just a syntax error.

```
type list = {
  value : int;
  mutable next : list1
  mutable prev : list1
}
and list1 = 
  Empty
| Node of list ;;

let rec insert sez x = 
  match sez with 
    Empty -> Node {value=x; prev=Empty; next=Empty}
  | Node {value=r; prev=lb; next=rb} -> 
    if x < r then Node {value=r; prev=(insert lb x); next=rb} 
    else Node {value=r; prev=lb; next=(insert rb x)};;
```

Comment: You're missing a semicolon between next and prev. I'm not able to reproduce the other error.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we have two lists - `L1` and `L2` - and position `k` to insert latter into former, the straightforward algorithm could look as follows:

1. Create a list that consists of first k elements of `L1` (let's name it `prefix`)
2. Create a list that consists of the rest of `L1` elements (let's name it `postfix`)
3. Concat `prefix`, `L2` and `postfix`

Prefix and postfix lists can be described as "take first k elements" and "drop first k elements and take the rest" - sounds quite familiar, right? So we can start with these auxiliary functions:

```
let rec take k lst =
  match k with
    | 0 -> []
    | k -> (match lst with
      | [] -> failwith "too short"
      | h::t -> h :: (take (k - 1) t))

let rec drop k lst =
  match k with
    | 0 -> lst
    | k -> (match lst with
      | [] -> failwith "too short"
      | h::t -> drop (k-1) t)
```

Now the solution becomes absolutely straightforward:

```
let insert l1 l2 n =
  match n with
    | 0 -> l2 @ l1
    | n ->
      if n = List.length l1 then l1 @ l2
      else (take n l1) @ l2 @ (drop n l1)
```

(not very efficient due to concatenation, but simple)

UPD. Actually, `insert` itself may be just as simple as

```
let insert l1 l2 n =
  (take n l1) @ l2 @ (drop n l1)
```

Comment: Thank you a whole lot, Konstantin!
Though I still get an error on the 6-th line, this is what the error says:
 
line 6, characters 27-34: 
Error: This expression has type int but an expression was expected of type 'a list

Now, here's the thing, if I replace the (k - 1) with (k - [1]), that you've added, the compiler then states directly the opposite:

line 6, characters 32-35:
Error: This expression has type 'a list
       but an expression was expected of type int.

I've also tested this with TryOcaml and I get the same result.

Comment: @OogeyBoogey there was some mess with the parameters' order, I've fixed it. Not it should work.

Comment: It works flawlessly, thank you Konstantin!
It really works like a charm. Now I can finally continue with my project, thanks again!